How do I find a point on a circle given a radius, center point and a unit vector of the line tangent to the point?
I have worked through trying to solve this problem for about 2 days now. I know I am close, but I just can't quite get there.
First, this question is coming up because of a problem I have at work with respect to finding nodes on a pipe elbow. Second, I have reached a solution that works for a specific case, but can't seem to make it work for other points I test.
Given:
Radius: $R$
Center of circle: $(cx, cy)$
Direction Vector of Tangent Line: $(vx, vy)$
Location of initial point $(x0, y0)$
I also have access to a direction vector of a line extending from the initial point (generally at the top of the circle). The location of that point can be arbitrary, though.
So essentially, what I know is that the equation for a point on a circle of radius $R$ is:
$$(x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2 = R^2$$
So that's my first constraint equation. Next I believe I have this correct, but the parametric equations of the line defined by the vector are: $$x = x0 +t*vx$$ $$y = y0 +t*vy$$
From this information I can use substitution, develop a quadradic and solve for the $t$, which will allow me to calculate X and Y.
So far though, this seems to only have worked with a 90 degree elbow. At this point I don't understand why it doesn't work for others.
As an example, if I have a unit circle and $(x0, y0) = (0, 0)$ and my direction vector is (0,-1), indicating the elbow is oriented in the negative Y direction it returns the point tangent to the circle as (1, -1) which is correct since it's 90 degrees and a radius of 1.
For example, refer to the figure below. Node 20 coordinates = (0, 0), Vector for line at node 20 = (1, 0), direction vector node 30 = (0, -1). From the equations above, node 30 is correctly (1, -1). I believe it also calculates node 25 as (0.43, -0.25) with a node 25 direction vector of (0.866, -0.5). However, I seem unable to then go from Node 25 and correctly calculate Node 30.
Elbow with intermediate point

I am really at a loss here. This is the input from a computer software from the 70s that generates an elbow as shown in the figure above. You can see the direction cosines (unit direction vectors)


This might be the first plumbing question on the site!

Yeah, it's an interesting situation. The software used in the above screenshots builds elbows based on direction cosines and radius of a circle. The new software that we're converting to uses x, y, z coordinates to build the elbow. So I needed a way to convert the information from the old one to the new one programmatically since we have hundreds of these old files.

You need to find the orientation of the end node based on the direction vector of tangent line.
The natural way of doing this is to take the arctangent of the slope of this vector and so look at $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)$ and thus find the angle of the radius, but there are two slight issues with this: (a) $v_x=0$ leads to an undesirable division by $0$; and (b) changing the signs of both components of the vector reverses the direction of the vector but would not change the arctangent of the quotient.
A way of handling both issues is to use the so-called atan2 function, being careful as some implementations reverse the two arguments and most return an angle in radians; you can use this to get the orientation of the tangent vector measured anti-clockwise from the positive $x$-axis, and the orientation of the corresponding radius vector is a right-angle more.
I will use $\theta = \frac\pi2+\operatorname{atan2}(v_x, v_y)$ and in your example $\frac\pi2+\operatorname{atan2}(0, -1) =\frac\pi2 -\frac\pi2=0$, i.e. $0^\circ$ so when the radius is pointing right (equivalent to the tangent vector pointing down).
In general the nodes for suitable $\theta$ are at
$$\big(c_x+R \cos(\theta),   c_y+R \sin(\theta)\big)$$
In your example, $(c_x,c_y)=(0,-1)$ and $R=1$,

so with $\theta = 0$  you would get the exit node at $(0+1 \times 1, -1+1 \times 0)=(1, -1)$ as expected
your starting node has $\theta = \frac\pi2$ or $90^\circ$ (the radius is pointing up) so is at $\left(0+1 \times 0, -1+1 \times 1\right) =(0,0)$ as expected
your intermediate node has $\theta = \frac\pi3$ or $60^\circ$ anti-clockwise from the $x$-axis so is at $\left(0+1 \times \frac12, -1+1 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}2\right) \approx(0.5,-0.134)$, which seems to match your diagram


I appreciate the response. This is helpful in understanding the steps. So, it boils down to calculating a theta based on the direction vectors, correct? The example for the intermediate note has an input direction vector of (0.866, -0.5), which seems to result in an angle of 30 degrees. I apologize if I am not understanding everything. I am a structural engineer just trying to figure out how using the X, Y, Z direction cosines + radius of an elbow gives me enough information to get the x, y, z, coordinates of any point. I appreciate the help.

@Jesselefty Your tangent vector of $(0.866, -0.5)$ for the intermediate node, more precisely $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2,-\frac12\right)$ is at an angle $-\pi/6 \approx -0.5236$ or $-30^\circ$ anti-clockwise from the horizontal found using atan2, so the radius vector is that plus a right angle i.e. $\theta=\pi/3$ or $+60^\circ$ anti-clockwise from the horizontal (which corresponds to $30^\circ$ clockwise from the vertical) and it is this $\theta=\pi/3\approx 1.0472$ to use in $\big(c_x+R \cos(\theta),   c_y+R \sin(\theta)\big)$.

Just so I am clear, if $theta < 0$ then I have to add $pi / 2$, otherwise if it's positive then I subtract $pi/2$?. I have been trying to read up on 'atan2' and it also seems like if I $theta$ is outside the range $(-pi, pi]$ then I need to add $2pi$.  I can't seem to get that worked out very easily in what it means when I have a x and y coordinates that may be in any quadrant of the circle.

If the flow round the corner is clockwise (as in your example), you are adding a right angle $\frac\pi 2$ to get from the tangent direction to the radius direction.  If it had been anticlockwise flow you would subtract  $\frac\pi 2$.  At any stage you can add or subtract $2\pi$ if you want as this is a full circle.
